# adding variable to var in php OOP?

Tags: php

i have a PHP file (maxProtector.class.php) and i am trying to get password from my website CP. So i want where is `var $password = '';` to make it `$password = $mypwfromMySQL`.
When i try var `$password = $row[password]`; i got error

```
<?php
class maxProtector {
    var $password = '';

    function showLoginForm(){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Вход в админ панела</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
       <div id="container">
            <div id="header"><div id="header_left"></div>
            <div id="header_main">ВХОД В АДМИН ПАНЕЛА</div><div id="header_right"></div></div>
            <div id="content">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                     <center>
                         <label>Парола:
                             <input name="passwd" type="password" size="20" />
                         </label><br/>
                         <label>
                             <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="ВЛЕЗ" />
                         </label>
                     </center>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.micro-invest.org" target="_blank">Powered by MICRO-INVEST.ORG</a></div>
         </div>
</body>      
<?php
    }

    function login(){
        $loggedin = isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ? $_SESSION['loggedin'] : false;
        if ( (!isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) && (!($loggedin))){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
               $this->showLoginForm();
               exit();
        } else if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {
               $pass = isset($_POST['passwd']) ? $_POST['passwd'] : '';

               if ($pass != $this->password) {
                   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
                   $this->showLoginForm();
                   exit();     
               } else {
                   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
               }
        }

    }
}

// Auto create
session_start();
$protector = new maxProtector();
$protector->login();
?>
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around your array key. It should be `$password = $row['password']`.

Comment: Don'y use it. This is old practice var $password = '';

Comment: @John , when i try i got: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /www/.../maxProtector.class.php on line 12

Comment: Make sure you have public/protected/private in front of it and a closing semi-colon at the end.

Comment: @TeodorNedialkov, give pls name of database where is password. And structure.

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev, table name is SETTINGS , row ADMINPASS

Comment: Version of php else please. Before construction var variable be workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
class maxProtector { 
  var $password; 

  function set_password($password) { 
    $this->password = $password; 
  } 

  function get_password() { 
    echo $this->password ;
    return $this->password ; 
  } 
} 

$o1 = new maxProtector; 
$o1->set_password($row['password']); 
echo $password = $o1->get_password();
?>
```

In method of class you are should call variable $this->pass for example

**UPDATE:**
But in php 5.3
not `var $pass` - `public/protected/static $pass`
not `function get_password()` -  `public/protected/static function get_password()`